# How to convert hex string to integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, syntax

How to convert

```
x = "0x000000001" # hex number string
```

to

```
y = "1"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
y = int("0x000000001", 16)
```

in your case:

```
y = int(x, 16)
```

Looks like you want the int converted to string:

```
y = str(int(x, 16))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) and provide the base which your number is in (in your case `16`).
Then apply [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) to convert it back to a string:

```
y = str(int(x, 16))
```

Note: If you omit the base then the default base `10` is used which would result in a `ValueError` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int("0x000000001", 16)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 have a problem to convert hex from read binary file

Python 3 not have this problem

```
f=open(file_name,'rb')
raw = f.read()

print int(raw[6])    #error invalid literal for int with base 10:
print ord(raw[6])    #Work
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
y = int(x, 0)  # '0' ;python intepret x according to string 'x'.
```

In the offical documentation, it is explained as "If base is zero, the proper radix is determined based on the contents of the string;"